# Creating a table reports with WTD

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How to create a table report with WTD integrated inside the report. e.g.

[image]

some option i could think of is creating an sp that returns a temp table, inside the sp is a loop that every week it will insert a wtd totals for that week. another one is if it can be achieved in the reporting service. so far no luck with those.

Comment: hi, take the week number of each date in SQL server then create a group of that week number and add the total for the same group.

Comment: then insert the wtd for every 7 days in temp table?

Comment: not required to do that, simply create a group of week numbers.

Comment: where should i create that? in the sp or in the ssrs?

Comment: *where should i create that? in the sp or in the ssrs?* - In SSRS.

Comment: @manoj how is that possible? i need it in order similar to what i have in the screenshot. after every end of week the wtd has to be provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grouping sets` and `order by`.  You don't show what your data looks like, but the idea is:

```
select date, sum(sales), sum(orders)
from t
group by grouping sets ( (date), (year(date), datepart(week, date)) )
order by max(date), grouping(date);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3367f7eb69cea9d851cce7d4fbe78e79) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This leaves the "WTD" out, because that is a string and you seem to want to put it in a `date` column.

You can convert the date to a string and use `coalece()` (or `case` logic using `grouping()`):

```
select coalesce(convert(varchar(255), date), 'WTD'),
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a4968d72d1d965bcc271844681764ad0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you sir! this is super helpful. however, im at lost on the ordering. how can i put the wtd groupset inside the date groupset. thanks in advance.

Comment: @user7414008 . . . This does the ordering as specified in the question.  I included a db<>fiddle.